# Adobe Air, Actionscript 3: Programmatically set the horizontalscrollpolicy in a scroller to off

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am wrapping a VGroup in a Scroller (by setting the scroller.viewport = vgroup), but I want to only be able to scroll vertically. In flex, a scroller component can set the "horizontalscrollpolicy" to "off", but programmatically in Actionscript 3, it does not seem to expose this attribute. How can I do this in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`horizontalScrollPolicy` is a style not a property. You can set it like this:

```
scroller.setStyle('horizontalScrollPolicy', ScrollPolicy.OFF);
```